# How to change color in the current website by using js?

Tags: javascript, web

I am very new in JS．I am trying to write a JS code to change color of the current link. For example, if it is in homepage, the color will be red, others are blue. But If I click SHOP tab, shop will turn to red, and others are blue.

This is my idea:

```
if(currentpage.href==one of a.href)
then a.style.color=red
```

I have searched so many pages, but when I tried to use them, some of them worked in the local computer, but none of them worked in the server.

Please, please help me!
Thank you for your time:)

```
<div  id="changeColor" class="horizontalcssmenu" style="padding-left:7px;">
<a href="linkeadress" >HOME</a>
<a href="linkaddress" >SHOP</a>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var links = document.getElementById("changeColor");
for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
{
  if(links.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].href == window.location.href)=function(){
    var tempLink=links.getElementsByTagName("a")[i];
    for(i=0;i<tempLink.length;i++){
      tempLink.style.color="#ff8100";
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Javascript has nothing to do with server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work if the links are fully qualified (meaning they'll match exactly what will come up in the address bar) http://jsfiddle.net/G7LGA/1/

If you have partial strings, let me know the format and i'll be able to update  the function to match better.

Comment: you should accept the answer so that others don't try to answer it

Answer (score 0):

its

```
tempLink.style.backgroundColor="#ff8100";
```

if you want to change the background color